# Implement c++ function inside or outside of namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am new to C++ and I want to know what is better/cleaner?

1. Implementing a function in a namespace
2. Use the fully qualified name to implement it

e.g:

```
//foo.h
namespace foo
{
    void bar();
}
```

1.)

```
//foo.cpp
namespace foo
{
    void bar()
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

or 2.)

```
//foo.cpp
void foo::bar()
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter, use what you feel more convenient with.

Comment: In 2, it is not obvious that `foo` is a `namespace` and not a `class`. with 1, you have extra block and so generally extra indentation.

Comment: In 2, the function definition must exactly match the definition of a previously declared function or else it will fail to compile. In 1, if the function definition doesn't match, you will define an overload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first option is better for grouping and putting together several functions of the same namespace, it's clearer and less verbose if you have more than one for example.

The second is semantically the same but is less eye friendly if you have many functions in the same namespace.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference *what-so-ever* to the resulting compiled code. It is purely a matter of style.

Use what you like the most (or what is currently the style-in-use of the code base you are working on).